kalman filter equations when I have position and velocity but force is unknown
I have a car for which I measure position and velocity using GPS receiver, but I do not know forces, which change the car velocity. I wonder how to build equations for Kalman filter. For measurements the H-matrix is easy
$\pmatrix{\hat x_k \cr \hat v_k} = \textbf{H}_k \pmatrix{x_k \cr v_k} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1} \pmatrix{x_k \cr v_k} $
However I have a problem with state equation, where I have the equation for the coordinate only
$x_{k+1} = x_k + v_k \Delta t$
It seems to me that as soon as $v_k$ is present in state vector I am forced to write some equation for $v_{k+1}$. But since I do not know external force, I do not know what to write... Should I assume zero force and write $v_{k+1} = v_k$ with
$\textbf{F}_k = \pmatrix{1 & \Delta t \cr 0 & 1}$
or is there another way to resolve this problem? The force which comes from the car engine changes its velocity but it is not a random force...
